# Select ViewName from Database depending on value entered

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called adverts and two tables called Sub Categories and child Categories some of the sub categories don't have child categories whilst others do.

So in the Adverts table the ChildCategoryId column could be null or it might have a value, depending on this I will return the relevant view to be displayed to the user.

So if the childCategoryId column has a value I power off that and return the ViewName that matches the childCategoryId from the ChildCategories table, if its null then I join on to SubCategory table and return the ViewName from there.

as follows my code looks like his

```
IF Exists(Select c.ViewName from Category.Child_Categories c
      inner join Advert.Adverts a on c.ChildCategoryId =a.ChildCatId
      where A.AdvertId = @ItemId and A.createdBy = @userID)
  Begin
      Select c.ViewName from Category.Child_Categories c
      inner join Advert.Adverts a on c.ChildCategoryId =a.ChildCatId
      where A.AdvertID = @ItemId and A.createdBy = @userID
  End
ELSE
  Begin
      Select s.ViewName from Category.Sub_Categories s
      inner join Advert.Adverts a on s.SubCategoryId =a.SubCatId
      where A.AdvertId = @ItemId and A.createdBy = @userID
  End
```

But to me the above looks a bit OTT for trying to do such a simple thing hence why I thought I'll ask on here to see if anyone else has a better way of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least you can simplify the IF condition by just looking for the relevant piece of info (i.e. is the ID field to JOIN on NULL or NOT NULL) rather than doing the JOIN itself:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT *
          FROM  Advert.Adverts a
          WHERE a.AdvertId = @ItemId
          AND   a.CreatedBy = @UserID
          AND   a.ChildCatId IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  SELECT c.ViewName
  FROM Category.Child_Categories c
  INNER JOIN Advert.Adverts a
          ON c.ChildCategoryId = a.ChildCatId
  WHERE a.AdvertID = @ItemId
  AND   a.CreatedBy = @UserID;
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT s.ViewName
  FROM Category.Sub_Categories s
  INNER JOIN Advert.Adverts a
          ON s.SubCategoryId = a.SubCatId
  WHERE a.AdvertId = @ItemId
  AND   a.CreatedBy = @UserID;
END;
```

Or, you can break it down to simpler queries by capturing the two fields that hold the relevant info, testing to see if one of them is NULL or NOT NULL, and then doing the second query against just the one table. This might make it easier on the optimizer to properly use the indexes. It is still 2 queries, just like the original code, but now without any JOINs.

```
DECLARE @ChildCatId INT,
        @SubCatId INT;

SELECT @ChildCatId = a.ChildCatId,
       @SubCatId = a.SubCatId
FROM   Advert.Adverts a
WHERE  a.AdvertId = @ItemId
AND    a.CreatedBy = @UserID;

IF (@ChildCatId IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  SELECT c.ViewName
  FROM   Category.Child_Categories c
  WHERE  c.ChildCategoryId = @ChildCatId;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT s.ViewName
  FROM   Category.Sub_Categories s
  WHERE  s.SubCategoryId = @SubCatId;
END;
```